# Triggering Event on Checkbox Click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am once again stuck with a jQuery issue, and I'm hoping for some help.

I have a series of checkboxes that look like these two:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="MultiPointInspection" id="MultiPointInspection" class="MultiPointInspection chkclass" value="<?php echo $MultiPointInspection; ?>" onKeyPress="return disableEnterKey(event)" />&nbsp;Multi Point Vehicle Inspection<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="TireRotationandBrake" id="TireRotationandBrake" class="add_to_total TireRotationandBrake chkclass" value="<?php echo $TireRotationandBrake; ?>" onKeyPress="return disableEnterKey(event)" />&nbsp;Tire Rotation and Brake Inspection<br />
```

What I want to do is add a new dynamic row to a previous table when any of these are clicked.  And I want to add the name, or id or whatever (they're all the same) for each one that is clicked into the description field.

This is the previous table:

```
<table id="atable" class="atable">
<tr>
<thead>
<th>Description</th><th>Stocked</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Part Price</th><th>Hours</th>    <th>Rate Class</th><th>Total</th><th>Approved</th><th>Remove Row</th></tr><thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="dynamic_row">
<td><input name="description[]" id="description" value="<?php echo $description; ?>" size="55" class="numeric add_to_total description" onKeyPress="return disableEnterKey(event)" />
</td><td align="center"><input type="checkbox"  name="stocked[]" id="stocked" value="<?php echo $stocked; ?>" size="5" class="numeric add_to_total" onKeyPress="return disableEnterKey(event)" />
</td><td><input name="quantity[]" id="quantity" value="<?php echo $quantity; ?>" size="5" class="numeric add_to_total quantity" onKeyPress="return disableEnterKey(event)" />
</td><td><input name="partPrice[]" id="partPrice" value="<?php echo $partPrice; ?>" size="10" class="numeric add_to_total part" onKeyPress="return disableEnterKey(event)" />
</td><td><input name="hours[]" id="hours" value="<?php echo $hours; ?>" size="10" class="numeric add_to_total hours" onKeyPress="return disableEnterKey(event)" />
</td><td><select name="rate[]" id="rate" class="numeric add_to_total rate" onKeyPress="return disableEnterKey(event)">
<?php
//get data from database for this field
?>
</select>
</td><td><input name="total[]" id="total" size="10" class="numeric is_total" readonly="readonly" onKeyPress="return disableEnterKey(event)" />
</td><td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="approved[]" id="approved" class="add_to_total approved" checked="checked" value="<?php echo $approved; ?>" size="10" onKeyPress="return disableEnterKey(event)" />
</td><td align="center"><img src="img/x.png" width="25" height="25" id="removeButton" title="Remove Row" class="delRow" />
</td></tr><tbody>
<tfoot><t<tr><td colspan="9" align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" border="0"><img src="img/plus.png" width="25" height="25" id="btnAddRow" title="Add New Row" class="alternativeRow" />
</td></tr><tfoot>
</table><br />
```

Of course, if the checkbox is unchecked, I want the row to be removed.

I've tried this, but it doesn't act at all:

```
$(function(){
$("#serviceRecommendation input:checkbox.chkclass").click(function(){
    if ($(this).is(":checked"))
    {
  $(this).closest("tr").clone().appendTo("#atable");
    }
    else
    {
      var index = $(this).closest("tr").attr("data-index");
      var findRow = $("#atable tr.dynamic_row");
      findRow.remove();
    }
  });
});
```

And I've also tried this for just the add (one step at a time, right), which includes the actual function that triggers the dynamic row add on an image click in the actual table.

```
$(".MultiPointInspection").bind('click',function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked"))
    {
    (".alternativeRow").btnAddRow({oddRowCSS:"oddRow",evenRowCSS:"evenRow"}).trigger();
    $(this).find(".description").val("Multi-Point Vehicle Inspection");
    }
});
```

This does not work either.

I've seen some similar posts, but none of them seem to be doing what I need to do.

I'm hoping someone has some insight for me on this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not surprised.  My HTML is just a snippet of the page, and I'm only working on functionality right now.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$("#MultiPointInspection,#TireRotationandBrake ").on('click', function(){
    if($(this).prop("checked"))
    {
        alert('checked');
        $('#atable tr:last').clone().appendTo("tbody");
    }
    else{
        alert('unchecked');
        // remove latest row in table
        $('#atable tr:last').remove();
    }   
});
```

I have created a fiddle with valid HTML

[`working DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/NhAJn/)

Comment: That works great in your demo, but not so much in mine.  The reason is that my last row is the "add row image".  I can play with that.  Unfortunately, your demo doesn't show how to remove that row when it is unchecked.  How hard would that be?

Comment: first of all use `jQuery v1.7` and now tell me : on uncheck you want to remove which row?? or you want to remove the row on click of the image of each one's last `td` ??

Comment: I am using 1.7.1, on uncheck I want to remove the row that was added when the checkbox was checked.

Comment: Not necessarily the latest.  If they check both boxes, I would want them to remove the correct one, which might not have been the latest.

Comment: how do i identify the row to be removed?? what do i match to remove the exact row?? because there is no data in your `HTML`. please make a fiddle for that.

Comment: That does remove the last row, but the last row contains my "add row image", so it disappears on uncheck.

Comment: Regarding your question, ideally, the content of the description field would be the option selected.  You could then match the value in that field on the uncheck.  At least that sounds good, I think :)

Comment: @WillSam :please make a `fiddle` with images and raw data and then write your question again. its 2:36 AM here. I have to sleep :)

Comment: I have managed to build a "working" fiddle - first time for everything.  [link](http://jsfiddle.net/2P46J/4/)  The problem with this is that it will not remove the row added, just the last one (because it's told to remove the last one), and of course, my pretty alternating rows don't work either with this (I could live with that).  Note that I had to add the jquery.table.addrow.js plugin content into the Javascript section to make it work.  I appreciate any continued help you can offer.

Comment: A couple of other issues arise with this.  In my real page, it adds two new rows, for some unknown reason.  It also adds a row to other tables (with different ids and classes) on the page.  This is truly baffling.  I'm hoping I can place the name or id or something else (a rel?) as the description in the new row.  And maybe that can be searched for to remove it on unclick?

Comment: See [link](http://jsfiddle.net/2P46J/5/) for example of mysteriously adding rows to other tables as per my last comment.

Comment: Reposted under the title [Adding Dynamic Row and Data on Checkbox Click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659155/adding-dynamic-row-and-data-on-checkbox-click) with a fiddle link, as per diEcho.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether a checkbox is checked or not, by doing the following:

```
$('#serviceRecommendation input:checkbox.chkclass').on('change', function(e) {
    if($('#' + e.target.id + ':checked').length > 0) {
        // Add the row
    } else {
        // Remove the row
    }
});
```

Comment: My issue with this one is trying to get it to trigger the Add Row function.  I can't seem to make that work, which is really what the goal is.