# Adding Dynamic Row and Data on Checkbox Click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am once again stuck with a jQuery issue, and I'm hoping for some help.

I have a series of checkboxes that look like these two:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="MultiPointInspection" id="MultiPointInspection" class="MultiPointInspection" value="<?php echo $MultiPointInspection; ?>" onKeyPress="return disableEnterKey(event)" rel="Multi Point Vehicle Inspection" />&nbsp;Multi Point Vehicle Inspection<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="TireRotationandBrake" id="TireRotationandBrake" class="TireRotationandBrake" value="<?php echo $TireRotationandBrake; ?>" onKeyPress="return disableEnterKey(event)" />&nbsp;Tire Rotation and Brake Inspection<br />
```

What I want to do is add a new dynamic row to a previous table (which I can already do with a separate button), but in this case, add the name, or id or class name (which are all the same as per above) as a textbox value in that row when any of these are clicked.  I also want them to remove when they are unclicked, but they won't always be the last row, so :last doesn't really work for me.

This is the previous table:

```
<table id="atable" class="atable">
<tr>
<td>Description</td><td>Stocked</td><td>Quantity</td><td>Part Price</td><td>Hours</td><td>Rate Class</td><td>Total</td><td>Approved</td><td>Remove Row</td></tr>
<tr class="dynamic_row">
<td><input name="description[]" id="description" value="<?php echo $description; ?>" size="55" class="numeric add_to_total description" onKeyPress="return disableEnterKey(event)" />
</td><td align="center"><input type="checkbox"  name="stocked[]" id="stocked" value="<?php echo $stocked; ?>" size="5" class="numeric add_to_total" onKeyPress="return disableEnterKey(event)" />
</td><td><input name="quantity[]" id="quantity" value="<?php echo $quantity; ?>" size="5" class="numeric add_to_total quantity" onKeyPress="return disableEnterKey(event)" />
</td><td><input name="partPrice[]" id="partPrice" value="<?php echo $partPrice; ?>" size="10" class="numeric add_to_total part" onKeyPress="return disableEnterKey(event)" />
</td><td><input name="hours[]" id="hours" value="<?php echo $hours; ?>" size="10" class="numeric add_to_total hours" onKeyPress="return disableEnterKey(event)" />
</td><td><select name="rate[]" id="rate" class="numeric add_to_total rate" onKeyPress="return disableEnterKey(event)">
<?php
    //get rate options from database
?>
</select>
</td><td><input name="total[]" id="total" size="10" class="numeric is_total" readonly="readonly" onKeyPress="return disableEnterKey(event)" />
</td><td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="approved[]" id="approved" class="add_to_total approved" checked="checked" value="<?php echo $approved; ?>" size="10" onKeyPress="return disableEnterKey(event)" />
</td><td align="center"><img src="img/x.png" width="25" height="25" id="removeButton" title="Remove Row" class="delRow" />
</td></tr>
<img src="img/plus.png" width="25" height="25" id="btnAddRow" title="Add New Row" class="alternativeRow" />    
</table>
```

I am using the [jQuery Table AddRow plugin](http://www.examplet.buss.hk/jquery/table.addrow.php).  I have used the following code to make it add the row, which is fine (although I don't get my pretty alternating rows), but it also adds the row to the bottom, below my "add row" button, so I'm also looking for a solution to the appendTo(), and would rather have it added just above the last row:

```
$("#MultiPointInspection,#TireRotationandBrake").on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
        $('#atable .dynamic_row:first').clone().appendTo("#atable");
    }
    else {
        $('#atable .dynamic_row:last').remove();
    }
});
```

and this is the regular code to add a row on the other button click:

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    $(".alternativeRow").btnAddRow({oddRowCSS:"oddRow",evenRowCSS:"evenRow"});
    $(".delRow").btnDelRow();
});
```

As if I'm not asking enough, what I would also like to do is not have the last column added for these rows.  The last column contains a link to remove the row, and I would only like the row to be removed on the unclick of the checkbox.

I have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2P46J/8/) with the basic setup of the problem (note the javascript contains the full jQuery Table AddRow plugin code), and would appreciate any help I could get with making this work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use `change` instead. Try something like

```
$("#MultiPointInspection,#TireRotationandBrake").on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('<tr><td><input type="text" id="'+$(this).attr("id")+'" 
              class="'+$(this).attr("class")+'" name="'+$(this).attr("name")+'"/>
                     </td></tr>').appendTo("#atable");
    }
    else {
        $('input#'+$(this).attr("id")+'[type="text"]').remove();
    }
});
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/dz2PR/1/